# How to clean obsolete and excluded files from Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a problem, with running some project on iPhone 4 device. It displays some excluded and already deleted XIB files. For contrast, on the simulator everything is OK. I deleted the app from device, and used xcode feature to clean the build, and there are still some obsolete versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down the Option key then select Product > Clean Build Folder... . This will completely wipe the build folder and you can then rebuild from a clean slate. If you also delete the app from your device then you can be sure that there are no leftovers from a previous build.